# Remove Unused Modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, yarnpkg

## **Problem**

I have created a react app that is currently 327.6 MB large. During development I got a little crazy with installing different modules. I want to streamline my app to remove all these unused node modules and packages. I know about npm prune but I don't completely understand how it works.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? The bundle size shouldn't be affected by unused packages as the bundler (webpack in your case?) does not include them. Even when using lots of libraries `327 MB` seems unusually big.

Comment: @trixn I am using webbpack but when I go to copy the folder it has over 80k files to copy. I even try to compress it and it is still 117MB

Comment: I see. You are copying all the dependencies in the `node_modules` folder. That's actually not your app but your development environment that is that big. Your app bundle (that what will be executed on the client) does only include what is actually being used and is much smaller. If you want to move your project somewhere else you usually exclude the node modules and execute `npm install` at the target system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**npm prune** will remove modules not listed in package.json.
To remove any specific node package, run the command **npm prune package_name**

For live-streaming ,If you want to get rid of the unused modules which are specified in 
**devDependencies** in **package.json** file, run this command.

> npm prune --production

For more-

> npm help prune